# Make a grid of perfectly square divs inside a div container... but what if the container is not a square?

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

Like I've written in the title I'm searching a way to make a grid of perfectly square divs even though the div container is a rectangle! My idea is that the user should be able to insert the values to change the grid and make it a new one. I created a function to make it possible setting the `height` and the `width` of the div container with equal values, but what if the height and width of the div container don't match? How can I make my little squares be perfectly square shaped even with the div container that is not a square?

Here's the function:

```
function makeGrid(n) {
const container = document.querySelector('#screen');
let divRow = undefined;

for (i = 0; n > i; i++) {
    divRow = document.createElement('div')
    container.appendChild(divRow);
}

const containers = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div');
let divColumn = undefined;

containers.forEach(function (e) {
    for (i = 0; n > i; i++) {
        divColumn = document.createElement('div');
        e.appendChild(divColumn)
    }
}) 
}
makeGrid(whatever number fits for a square, but for a rectangle?);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of a single input `n`, you'll need two separate inputs for the number of squares in each row and the number of squares in each column.  These can be different from each other, and will determine the container's width and height.  Then in your `for` loops, instead of going from 0 to n, the one for rows will go up to the first number and the one for columns will go up to the second.

Comment: The div container's width should be divisible by the number of columns, while its height should be divisible by the number of rows (by the same factor).  This will keep the squares square, without assuming width == height

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Hi! Yeah the first thing that I though after to have published the question was to set two variables as parameters and assign the first to the first loop and the second to the second loop. But the problem is that the rectangle height and width are set. The rectangle shape stays the same and doesn't depend on the squares inside it

Comment: Oh, then I misinterpreted your question.  It looks like IT goldman's answer might help you since it assumes a fixed container size.  When I ran the snippet, it looks like it does what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

If the container size is a given, you would need the ratio of number of squares on each side to be same as of `width / height` of container. This is for an integer count of squares on each side.

Let's say the size of rectangle is 240x170. The reduced fraction is 24/17 so those should be the number of squares on each side (or a multiplication of it by an integer). The size of each square then is pretty much determined for you. You can only control the scale of it (n=1, n=2 etc).

For best result use numbers that divide "well".

```js
const gcd = (...arr) => {
  const _gcd = (x, y) => (!y ? x : gcd(y, x % y));
  return [...arr].reduce((a, b) => _gcd(a, b));
};

function makeGrid(n) {
  const container = document.querySelector('#screen');
  var w = container.clientWidth
  var h = container.clientHeight
  var d = gcd(w, h);
  d = d / n
  var x = w / d; 
  var y = h / d;

  let divRow = undefined;
  for (i = 0; y > i; i++) {
    divRow = document.createElement('div')
    container.appendChild(divRow);
  }

  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div');
  let divColumn = undefined;

  containers.forEach(function(e) {
    for (i = 0; x > i; i++) {
      divColumn = document.createElement('div');
      e.appendChild(divColumn)
      divColumn.classList.add("square")
      divColumn.style.width = (d) + "px"
      divColumn.style.height = (d) + "px"
    }
  })
}


makeGrid(1)
// makeGrid(2)
// makeGrid(6)
```

```css
#screen {
  width: 240px;
  height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.square {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#screen>div:nth-child(odd) .square:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}

#screen>div:nth-child(even) .square:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
</div>
```